# Where are the Java System Packages stored?

Tags: java, package, file-structure

I want to see all the java packages. Where are the packages stored in my machine? Can anyone help. I did search in jdk folder and found awt.dll and all. But its only a few. Can i see all of them?

Comment: What OS are you dealing with?

Answer (score 32):

If you want a list of packages in the standard installation, just go to the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html) and look in the upper left corner.

If you want to see the .class files, they're in `lib\rt.jar` in the JRE directory (`.jar` is the same as `.zip`, so you can open it with anything that can open zip files).

If you want to see the source code, look in `src.zip` in the JDK directory. If it's not there, you probably elected not to install it when you installed the JDK.

Keep in mind that packages are represented as folders on disk, so you might be a little disappointed by what you see.

Answer (score 23):

From Java 9 onwards `rt.jar` was [removed](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220)

> The class and resource files previously stored in `lib/rt.jar`, `lib/tools.jar`, `lib/dt.jar`, and various other internal JAR files are now stored in a more efficient format in implementation-specific files in the lib directory. The format of these files is not specified and is subject to change without notice.

The System class files can now be accessed as shown below

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"));
Path objClassFilePath = fs.getPath("modules", "java.base", "java/lang/Object.class");
```

Comment: How to call this in python? , we have a python script where we used rt.jar, now after upgrading java we are facing errors

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean the packages that include the class libraries like java.lang.* and java.util.*, these live in the "lib" directory under wherever your Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is installed.

On Windows, it would be something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_12\lib
```

In there, you should see files like `rt.jar` which contains the core Java classes and `charsets.jar` which contains many of the extended encoding support for EBCDIC and the CJK languages.

In a parallel `bin` directory are the executables for Java and related utilities.

If you've installed the Java Development Kit (JDK), in the directory above where you find the libs you will probably find a `src.jar` file. This can be unpacked either with the `jar.exe` utility, or with a standard *zip*-style tool, and contains the Java sources to the standard class library.

Some of Java, such as the virtual machine itself, is machine-specific, and will be part of some of the DLL's or EXE's present.

Answer (score 5):

You can try unzipping/unjarring rt.jar, which is usually available in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/rt.jar`.  The jar file should include the classfiles of all the `JDK`, if that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows:**

For compressed compiled java packages( Java Class Library, JCL): program files/java/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar

For source of packages: program files/java/jdk/src.zip

we can use any unzipping software to look into them.

Answer (score 1):

My JDK 1.6.0_13 has a src.zip containing all the source code.  Give that a look.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @VenkataRaju i would like to put 2 more points that

1. we have ./bin, ./conf, ./include, ./jmods, ./legal, ./lib
2. we can see all the classlist in ./lib/classlist and ./lib/src.jar
   in java 11

Answer (score 0):

`rt.jar` is removed since Java 9. So, to find sources of JCL you should:

```
sudo find / -name java.base
```

Answer (score 0):

In a JDK version 18.0.1.1, all packages are present in the jrt-fs.jar file.

path:- jdk-18.0.1.1\lib\jrt-fs.jar.

inside this jrt-fs.jar file, all pre-defined classes are present in the package path like java\io for java.io, java\lang for java.lang, java\util for java.util, java\sql for java.sql etc..

Answer (score 0):

As some of the users mentioned already, it can be found at:
/Java/jdk-21/lib/src.zip/

Terminal need to be elevated to Admn mode: Win

Example: Java File method is under IO package.

/Java/jdk-21/lib/src.zip/java.base/java/io