# JDK 14 doesn't have rt.jar with it. Where are bootstrap classes then?

Tags: java, java-9, java-14, rt.jar

The **only** *jar* file I could find inside JAVA-HOME/lib was a file called ***jrt-fs.jar*** which is only 105 KB in size.

So where are Runtime (bootstrap) classes then?

Comment: The classes are in the file `lib/modules`. This is a binary file which can be read with JRT file system.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `rt.jar` file was removed in Java 9, but if you need to *access* the classfiles in the runtime, you can do so easily through the JRT file system.  See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897006/3553087.

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46451977/2711488), which also addresses the purpose of the remaining `jrt-fs.jar`.

Answer (score 4):

Allow me to [quote the migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-A78CC891-701D-4549-AA4E-B8DD90228B4B):

> Class and resource files previously stored in `lib/rt.jar`, `lib/tools.jar`, `lib/dt.jar` and various other internal JAR files are stored in a more efficient format in implementation-specific files in the `lib` directory.

Comment: Waiting for [Naman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746118)'s comment saying: *"Or you could just visit [xy](http://xy) website which will load contents faster"* ;)

Comment: ...and the [JEP-220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) as quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244168/1746118) already clarifies this with more details. If it was for specifically jrt-fs, Brian and Holger made the point pretty clear with the links they'd shared.